# How to write a XPath to get all parents that have two known children?

Tags: xpath

I have this kind of node in my xml document:

```
<parent ...>
   <a .../>
   <b .../>
</parent>
```

Parent node can have both a and b, only a, only b, or none of them. I want to write a XPath to get all parents that have both. Can I do that?

Parent can have also other children.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<element>
  <a/>
  <b/>
</element>

element[child::a][child::b]
```

this should select all the elements with a and b as direct children, regardless if they have additional children or not.  Or, more simply:

```
element[a][b]
```

...I think.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

//[a and b]

Comment: Do you want to search for parent nodes named 'parent' specifically or find any node with an 'a' and 'b' child element?

Answer (score 1):

```
//*[child::a and child::b]
```

Answer (score 1):

Obvious:

```
parent[a and b]
```

The child axis is implicit in predicates, this means there is no need to mention it.

```
parent[child::a and child::b]   <!-- the same, only longer -->
```

The use of two separate predicates is possible as long as the conditions are conjunctive ("and"):

```
parent[a][b]  <!-- the same, slightly shorter -->
```

This saves three characters in expression length. However, the use of two predicates triggers two separate checks, since they are applied one after another. Using *one* predicate with a boolean operator seems to be the simplest and cleanest approach to me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 //parent[count(a) > 0 and count(b) > 0]
```

should do it. There's a great XPath testbed [here](http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm) that makes life very easy, in terms of highlight the matched nodes etc.

Comment: that would have to be parent::*[count(a) > 0 and count (b) >0], wouldn't it?

Comment: @Brian Agnew: no, you're right - I was confusing an element named "parent" and the parent:: xpath axis.  Mea Culpa.